Parity of the solution of Schrodinger equation
When the potential function is an even function, the solution of the Schrodinger equation can be chosen to be an odd function or an even function. I know how to prove this for certain examples, e.g. this & this Phys.SE posts.
Additionally I observed that if the ground state function is even, then the 1st excited state is odd, the 2nd excited state is even, etc. in every example problem that I solved. I would like to know when this holds, and why this holds.

Hint: Use the node theorem.

Have you read quantum mechanics books? this is a well known fact that can be used to reduce calculations.

Following Qmechanic's suggestion, excellent resource here
